# Traveling with my 5 year old daughter (as the father) without the mother from Germany to Mexico

Tags: legal, germany, children, mexico

I will be flying with my 5 year old daughter without the mother to Mexico from Germany with transit in the United States. Her grandmother on her mom's side will also be traveling with us.

I was born in Mexico and have acquired German citizenship and kept the Mexican one. I will be traveling with my German passport. I am separated from the mother (she is German; we were never married), but I still have a good relationship with her. My daughter was named according to Mexican law, so her last name is my first last name and her mother's (maiden) last name (to give an example with a fake name: Ana Maria González Müller). Something to note is that the mother has since married someone else and took his name, so her last name is no longer the one on my daughter's last name.

I bought the ticket through Lufthansa but I believe the airline will be United Airlines.

My question is: Is there something I should consider while traveling with my daughter regarding boarding the plane, going through customs or similar? Should I get a signed letter from the mother or something? I will be for sure carrying her birth certificate. What else can I do or take with me?

Edit: 
-The mother and I have shared custody.
-To clarify, I will be entering Mexico with with my Mexican passport as it is required by Mexican law. My daughter has never been to the Mexican consulate in Germany and hence has no Mexican passport or birth certificate.

**Update: We will be writing a letter of consent in English, German and Spanish, and we will go to the city hall to get the mom's signature notarized**

Thank you

**Follow-up: We are back in Germany and everything went smoothly. I took with me a bunch of documents from my daughter including vaccination certificates, but all that was needed was the notarized letter of consent from the mother at the passport control when leaving Germany (apart from the passports and ESTA, of course). For future reference, we got the signatures on the letters notarized at the city hall (Rathaus) and it costed 1,50€ per stamp. Thanks to everyone who answered and commented!**

Comment: Which airline(s)? It would be worth checking whether they have any specific requirements (although the answer from o.m. below probably covers it)

Comment: I bought the tickets through Lufthansa but I believe the operating airline will be United Airlines. I will edit the question with this information.

Comment: Dont forget to make sure she is up to date on her vaccines, bring a bottle of Kaopectate, and a bottle of cipro (just in case)

Comment: Thanks, vaccines and good health insurance are taken care of. Is there a particular reason you mentioned both of these drugs?

Comment: Have good insurance, and have instructions for her care if anything happens to you. If you do have an accident or get sick, you may be considered in neglect. It sounds extreme, but consider the downside.

Comment: who has legal custody of the child? You, the mother or shared?

Comment: @Tom we have shared custody, thanks for bringing that up. I have edited the post.

Comment: Here is a suggestion for a letter you can take with you: https://www.adac.de/der-adac/rechtsberatung/reiserecht/reisevollmacht-kinder/

Comment: "I will be traveling with my German passport." Some countries require citizens to enter with that country's passport, you should check if Mexico does.

Comment: Even if your daughter does not have a maxican passport, she might have mexican nationality and might be requiered as well to enter Mexico with a mexican passport.

Comment: @lalala I have spoken to the Mexican consulate and they have told me "it is not required but advisable".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- If you do not have sole custody, get a [letter](https://www.bundespolizei.de/Web/DE/01Sicher-auf-Reisen/06Passrechtliche-Hinweise/02Reisen-mit-Kindern/reisen-mit-kindern_node.html) from the mother stating that she has no objection.
- The child's passport.
- Possibly a transit visa for all concerned.

---

Follow-Up: As far as Germany is concerned, the letter need not be notarized but it should contain the current contact details of the other legal guardian.

Comment: I would suggest to add something that would easily prove that the woman traveling with you is the child's maternal grandmother. Her saying "yes, my daughter is aware and OK with this" will certainly be invaluable in case some official gets suspicious.

Comment: I would also recommend that you ask the mother to have her letter notarized, which is basically a legal attestation that the child's mother was positively identified and confirmed to have signed the letter.

Comment: And if you do have sole custody a document showing that would be helpful.

Comment: @DJClayworth The mom and I have shared custody. I have all my documents regarding my custody rights.

Comment: If he does have sole custody (very unlikely given the grandmother), he should bring the relevant court decree. **OP:** The notarized letter is essential. I suggest, in fact, that you bring a certified Spanish translation (or a notarized Spanish version), so that you do not have problems being admitted to Mexico.

Comment: No sense to get a transit visa for this situation if you don't need one otherwise. An unnecessary transit visa would only make the case more suspicious.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I think that the main difficulty will be leaving the Schengen space. Mexico will not mind having a Mexican bring his daughter along; on the contrary, typically the home countries of separated parents support their case even in illegal cases which amount to "child abduction" and don't e.g. extradite upon US parents' request, warrented as they may be.

Comment: I would also strongly suggest including a copy of the child's Birth Certificate in the list documents. Hopefully that document also includes the Father's name.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Germany is notorious for ignoring The Hague Convention on custody, but I’m not sure Mexico would be as corrupt.

Answer (score 13):

US authorities are generally very aware of potential 'abductions' of children by one parent (*against* the consent of the other parent); especially for international travel.
Now that should not affect you much, as you are not taking the child out of the US, but simply 'transiting', but it could be they ask you.

The strong recommendation for the US is to have a signed letter from the other parent; if you want to avoid trouble, this would be a good idea to bring.

Comment: Transiting in the US means that you are admitted temporarily and then leave-- unlike many countries there are no sterile transit areas in US airports, so it's not as special as it might be.

Comment: I am aware of that; but you would have boarding passes from the incoming flight, so it is easy to show that you are not bringing a child out of the US, but _through_ the US. That would make it a lot less probable for US authorities to consider an abduction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one mentioned it but in addition to the documentation that @o.m. listed, I would also include a **copy of the child's birth certificate**. Hopefully this document includes the OPs legal name which would be a good document to show their legal relationship to the child.

I have traveled multiple times with my preschool age son (across state lines but always within the US) and per recommendations by the airlines always bring along a copy of this document. I have yet to been asked to provide it by the airlines or security but it gives me comfort in knowing that if ever questioned I could provide legal documentation of my relationship to my child.

Examples of recommendations from airlines:

- https://www.allegiantair.com/traveling-with-children
- https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/traveling-children.jsp
- https://www.lawdepot.com/blog/3-documents-every-parent-needs-when-traveling-with-children/

Comment: In my experience the airline and border control personnel never ask for a birth certificate to prove a relationship between parents and children.